# Using ant to run a custom java task can't find the class files

Tags: java, ant

I'm trying to run a custom java task using ant with the custom task already successfully complied into the .class file. This custom task will call another class in an application, in theory running that program via command line.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <project default="main" name="myproject">
    <property name="distDir" location=".\dist\" />
<property name="mainDir" location=".\" />
<property name="host" value=""/>
<property name="port" value=""/>
<property name="dir" value=""/>
<property name="startTest" value=""/>
<property name="endTest" value=""/>
<property name="testOnly" value=""/>
<property name="userName" value=""/>
<property name="passwd" value=""/>
    <taskdef name="mytask" classname="Classrunner">
        <classpath>  
            <fileset dir="${distDir}>
                <includes="*.jar">
            </fileset>
         </classpath>
    </taskdef>
    <target name="main">
        <mytask host="${host}" port="${port}" dir="${dir}" startTest="${startTest}" endTest="${endTest}" testOnly="${testOnly}" userName="${userName}" passwd="${passwd}"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

The taskdef part of my ant file specifies a fileset that contains a directories that has all the jars in it to run application I'm trying to run. The problem I'm running into is whenever I invoke ant via the command line and pass all the right parameters, and then I get an error saying "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/pega/fuzz/player/CustomClass"

CustomClass is the class that I call in my custom file and it exists inside that directory of all the jar files so I'm not sure how to specify where it lives since Ant can't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone at work helped me figure out a way to fix this.

The best way is if you set the environment variable, classpath, through a .bat file like so:

```
set "CURRENT_DIR=%~dp0"
cd %CURRENT_DIR%
set "CLASSPATH=%CURRENT_DIR%\dist\bsf-2.3.0.jar;%CURRENT_DIR%\....   "
```

From there you can then set a variable for ant and run your ant file right from here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the classpath attribute of the taskdef tag.
See the docs here: http://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-writing-tasks.html#use1

Comment: The issue isn't finding the custom task I've written, it's finding the classes that my custom task references.

Comment: I see what you mean. Are you sure its inside one of the jar files? Is it in the correct package?

Comment: The directory that ${distDir} points to has all the jar files needed. And I went in manually with WinZip and took a look and it's there. It seems like there's a few people that have had this problem but there's not really a solution.

Comment: You could debug it, put a breakpoint on your task class (the one that's loading OK), and check the stack. Then you can maybe see what the classloader configuration is doing.